# Get items from multidimensional list Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list with the following appearance:

```
 [0] = [ [0.0, 100.0], [0.1, 93.08], [0.3, 92.85], [0.5, 92.62], [0.7, 91.12], [0.9, 90.89] ]

 [1] = [ [0.0, 100.0], [0.1, 2.79], [0.3, 2.62], [0.5, 2.21], [0.7, 1.83], [0.9, 1.83] ]
```

and I´d like to obtain vectors to plot the info as follows:

```
[0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
[100.0, 93.08, 92.85, 92.62, 91.12, 90.89]
```

and the same with all entries in the list.
I was trying something like:

```
x = mylist[0][:][0]
```

Any ideas? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Is this just python or numpy?

Comment: Just pyhton. I should've used numpy but it's too late now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> mylist = [
    [0.0, 100.0], [0.1, 93.08], [0.3, 92.85], [0.5, 92.62],
    [0.7, 91.12], [0.9, 90.89] ]
>>> a, b = zip(*mylist)
>>> a
(0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9)
>>> b
(100.0, 93.08, 92.85, 92.62, 91.12, 90.89)

>>> list(a)
[0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
>>> list(b)
[100.0, 93.08, 92.85, 92.62, 91.12, 90.89]
```

Comment: Dang it, I had this answer, plus a whole Devo 'when a problem comes along you must zip it' joke going on :(

Comment: one line solution: `a, b = map(list, zip(*data))`

Answer (score 5):

With pure-python you should use [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
data = [ [0.0, 100.0], [0.1, 93.08], [0.3, 92.85], [0.5, 92.62], [0.7, 91.12], [0.9, 90.89] ]
listx = [item[0] for item in data ]
listy = [item[1] for item in data ]

>>>listx
[0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
>>>listy
[100.0, 93.08, 92.85, 92.62, 91.12, 90.89]
```

I think its a bit better than **zip** because it is easier to read and you do not have to cast the tuples

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` solution:

```
import numpy as np
data = [ [0.0, 100.0], [0.1, 93.08], [0.3, 92.85], [0.5, 92.62], [0.7, 91.12], [0.9, 90.89] ]
data_np = np.array(data)
a = data_np[:,0]
b = data_np[:,1]

In [126]: a
Out[126]: array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.3,  0.5,  0.7,  0.9])

In [127]: b
Out[127]: array([ 100.  ,   93.08,   92.85,   92.62,   91.12,   90.89])
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `map` too:

```
a = map(lambda x: x[0], your_list)
b = map(lambda x: x[1], your_list)
```